# Simplifying code to simultaneously perform functions on 12 worksheets quickly

Tags: performance, excel, excel-2007, vba

I am using the following code which is working successfully.

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rngMyRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

 Sheets("Jan").Activate
 Sheets("Jan").Select
 Cells.Select
 Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Set rngMyRange = Range("JanRangeTotal")
    For Each cell In rngMyRange.Cells
        cell.Select
        If cell.Value = "" Then GoTo DOTHETHING
    Next cell

DOTHETHING:
    Selection.Resize(1812).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Sheets("Jan").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(Array("Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec") _
        ).Select
    Sheets("Feb").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets(Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", _
        "Dec")).Select
    Sheets("Feb").Activate
    Range("C7").Select
    Sheets("PO to Complete").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, it is taking about 15 seconds to run and having switched screenupdating on it's the mass copy and paste exercise which is eating the most time. So I thought how about putting the array select further up the code so that it would DOTHETHING to all sheets and remove the need to copy and paste formats from "Jan" to all the other month sheets.  I came up with the code below:

```
Sub Button2_Click()

    Dim rngMyRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

 Sheets("Jan").Activate
 Sheets("Jan").Select
 Cells.Select
 Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Set rngMyRange = Range("JanRangeTotal")
    Sheets(Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", _
    "Dec")).Select
    Sheets("Jan").Activate
    For Each cell In rngMyRange.Cells
        cell.Select
        If cell.Value = "" Then GoTo DOTHETHING
    Next cell

DOTHETHING:
    Selection.Resize(1812).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("C7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets("PO to Complete").Select

End Sub
```

But it's not performing the row-hide command on the other sheets.  Is there a way for me to get this to work faster?

Cheers,

DuNk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the select command? This is very slow.

I also don't think it is working as you think it is. I don't think you can hide rows by selecting across sheets which is why this is failing.

Why don't you try declaring the ranges on each sheet and looping through the sheets using something like

```
application.screenupdating = false
dim ws as worksheet

for each ws in thisworkbook.sheets
    ' Your Code here
next ws
```

This would be faster with declared ranges (there's no point in selecting the cells unless it is for a visual thing which I'm assuming it isn't as you are turning the screen updating off)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I declared the ranges on each tab and basically repeated the first part of the code for each of the 12 month sheets.  It now runs in 3seconds!